# Retain css of links after enabling click-tracking of send-grid

Tags: css, hyperlink, sendgrid, click-tracking

I am trying to send a button through sendgrid using their click tracking but they change the link when being delivered to enable tracking. and that changes the css of the link. how do i keep the css and enable click tracking using sendgrid. I am using node-mailer for rendering and sending of mail with send-grid-transport. you can see the screenshots below for better understanding

**without click tracking enabled:**

[image]

**with click tracking enabled:**

[image]

EDIT:

the code for my button is below

```
<a href={{'https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='+url}} style="margin:20px 20%;border:1px solid;display:block;padding:10px 16px;text-decoration:none;border-radius:2px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;white-space:nowrap;background:#ffffff;border-color:#3a5795;background-color:#3a5795;color:#ffffff;border-top-width:1px" target="_blank">
                  Share on Facebook
              </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use inline styling and add the CSS as part of the  tag. That won't be changed by SendGrid.

Comment: yes that is what i did . you can see my code in the updated part of question

Comment: A simple change, but have you tried defining the style first? I know other SendGrid customer are able to have this work.

Comment: as you can see in my code above i gave all style inline. and can you clarify what you mean by 'defining style first?'. i am using mail-gun and its working great. rendering and everything working exactly like it should. but in SendGrid its not.